# Is there a simple way to convert a 2d list of floats into a 2d list of tuples in python?

Tags: python, list, tuples

Let's say I have a 2d list of floats, so something such as

```
[[0.1, 0.2], [1.1, 1.2]]
```

I would like to convert this to something such as

```
[[(0, 0.1), (0, 0.2)], [(0, 1.1), (0, 1.2)]]
```

I'm wondering if there is a better or shorter way of doing this then using a loop like the following

```
for i in range(len(float_array)):
     for j in range(len(float_array[i])):
          float_array[i][j] = (0, float_array[i][j])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Nested* [List comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> l = [[0.1, 0.2], [1.1, 1.2]]
>>> [[(0, val) for val in elem] for elem in l]
[[(0, 0.1), (0, 0.2)], [(0, 1.1), (0, 1.2)]]
```